# Metal Performance Shader to add Noise

Tags: swift, metal

Are there any Metal Performance Shaders that can add Noise to my MTLTexture? - I'm aware of shaders like: MPSImageGaussianBlur, but one to add noise would be excellent!

Comment: I've written a noise library here: https://github.com/AndyHeardApps/AHNoise feel free to rip the simplex function out of it for use in your own kernels.

Comment: Worth noting that it is a work in progress, but it outputs noise textures ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are currently no noise filters in MPS. You should [file an enhancement Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) with your anticipated use case and the types of noise you'd like to see supported (value, gradient (Perlin), Worley; single octave or fractal; dimensionality (1D, 2D, 3D); static or animated; etc.)

Comment: "If it's not in Radar, it didn't happen."